# What is the return type of a SQL query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, mariadb

I have a mariadb database and connect to it with their connector through nodejs. I send a select query. When I log the returned values i get this:

```
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        heading: 'Test Heading',
        url: 'test-heading',
        content: '#This is Test Content!',
        author: 'Max Mustermann'
      },
      meta: [
        ColumnDef {
          _parse: [StringParser],
          collation: [Collation],
          columnLength: 11,
          columnType: 3,
          flags: 16899,
          scale: 0,
          type: 'LONG'
        },
        ColumnDef {
          _parse: [StringParser],
          collation: [Collation],
          columnLength: 1020,
          columnType: 253,
          flags: 4097,
          scale: 0,
          type: 'VAR_STRING'
        },
        ColumnDef {
          _parse: [StringParser],
          collation: [Collation],
          columnLength: 1020,
          columnType: 253,
          flags: 20485,
          scale: 0,
          type: 'VAR_STRING'
        },
        ColumnDef {
          _parse: [StringParser],
          collation: [Collation],
          columnLength: 4294967295,
          columnType: 252,
          flags: 4113,
          scale: 0,
          type: 'BLOB'
        },
        ColumnDef {
          _parse: [StringParser],
          collation: [Collation],
          columnLength: 200,
          columnType: 253,
          flags: 0,
          scale: 0,
          type: 'VAR_STRING'
        }
      ]
    ]
```

I interpret this as a list of objects which are the found entries in the database. But why can there be a key value pair right behind that (the meta key) without needing curly braces around it? When I try to store this exact structure to a variable by hand I get an error. The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#json-result-sets) says the return type is a JSON object. Can someone please explain what is going on here? Thanks (Guesses are welcome as well)

Here is my Code:

```
  const config = require("./config.js");
  const mariadb = require("mariadb");
  
  const pool = mariadb.createPool({
      host: config.db_host,
      user: config.db_user,
      password: config.db_password,
      connectionLimit: 5,
      database: config.db_name
  });
  
  pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
      console.log("Connected to MariaDB Database");
  
      conn.query("select * from BlogEntries where url=(?);"["test-heading"]).then((rows)=>{
          console.log(rows)
          conn.end();
      }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
          conn.end();
      })
  
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Failed to connect to MariaDB Database:",err);
  
  })
```

config.js exports the ports etc (that works) otherwise really nothing special here. My Database looks like this (url is unique and id is the primary key):

```
MariaDB [Paulemeister]> select * from BlogEntries;
+----+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
| id | heading         | url          | content                | author         |
+----+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Test Heading    | test-heading | #This is Test Content! | Max Mustermann |
|  2 | Minimal Heading | bare-minimum |                        | NULL           |
+----+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to make and retrieve the query.

Comment: You are interpreting a console log, which formats things for human readability, as something which would represent code 1:1. That's not how `console.log` works.

Comment: That looks more like a document definition then a query result set. Seeing the code you are running will help in analyzing this.

Comment: Ok sorry for not including code, changed it. When I change the console.log(rows) to  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))) it outputs the same, except for everything after `meta:`. Why is that? Shouldn't  that output the same as before? I would appreciate it if you would help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MariaDB documentation this is the data key/value pairs you are looking for:

```js
      {
        id: 1,
        heading: 'Test Heading',
        url: 'test-heading',
        content: '#This is Test Content!',
        author: 'Max Mustermann'
      },
```

The `meta` section is reference to the database column data types.

Data rows are `rows: [ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]` where the first element of each row array is the data, the second is the meta information. Perhaps this will be of assistance: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connector-nodejs-callback-api/#result-set-array

It appears that the nodejs library has a node event structure for retrieving the data. An example from the url referenced above:

```js
connection.query("SELECT * FROM mysql.user")
      .on("error", err => {
        console.log(err); //if error
      })
      .on("fields", meta => {
        console.log(meta); // [ ... ]
      })
      .on("data", row => {
        console.log(row);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        //ended
      });
```

use the `.on('data', row => {...` to put all your data rows in an array and work with them from there.

What do you mean by this?

> When I try to store this exact structure to a variable by hand I get an error.